# Getting inputs from comboboxes doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I made a couple of combo-boxes, where the User can choose between pre-defined settings:

```
# create comboboxes for settings
combobox_sensortype = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('RGB','MS'), state='readonly').grid(row=3,column=2)
combobox_dem_dop = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('DEM','DOP'), state='readonly').grid(row=4,column=2)
combobox_sensortype_def = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('RGB_HZ','RGB_MR','MS_HZ','MS_MR'), state='readonly').grid(row=5,column=2)
combobox_run_SAGA_bat = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('Yes','No'), state='readonly').grid(row=6,column=2)
   
# getters for extracting user input from comboboxes
sensortype = combobox_sensortype.get()
demdop = combobox_dem_dop.get()
sensortype_def = combobox_sensortype_def.get()
run_SAGA_bat = combobox_run_SAGA_bat.get()
```

Unfortunately, I get this:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'**

Whats the issue here?
I really hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you called the method `.grid(row=3,column=2)`. This doesn't return anything, thus the variable's value was set to `None`. To get your result, put them in separate lines. So you should define the Combobox, then grid it.

**Solution:**

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# create comboboxes for settings
combobox_sensortype = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('RGB', 'MS'), state='readonly')  # define the combobox
combobox_sensortype.grid(row=3, column=2)  # grid it!

combobox_dem_dop = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('DEM', 'DOP'), state='readonly')
combobox_dem_dop.grid(row=4, column=2)

combobox_sensortype_def = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('RGB_HZ', 'RGB_MR', 'MS_HZ', 'MS_MR'), state='readonly')
combobox_sensortype_def.grid(row=5, column=2)

combobox_run_SAGA_bat = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('Yes', 'No'), state='readonly')
combobox_run_SAGA_bat.grid(row=6, column=2)

# getters for extracting user input from comboboxes
sensortype = combobox_sensortype.get()
demdop = combobox_dem_dop.get()
sensortype_def = combobox_sensortype_def.get()
run_SAGA_bat = combobox_run_SAGA_bat.get()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ohh that thing again. It works now, thank you man!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)